# Beautiful Soup Error AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to write a program using BeautifulSoup and Requests. There are a bunch of XML files which I have extracted from a large XML document and stored them into a dict called `all_sitemaps` with respective country name. Each dict key is mapped against bunch of xml files associated with each country and looks like below:

```
{'uk/en': ['file-1.xml',
  'file-2.xml',
  'file-3.xml',
  'file-4.xml'],
 'ca/en': ['file-1.xml',
  'file-2.xml',
  'file-3.xml']}
```

Next step is to run a GET requests on each individual .xml files and extract certain nodes and their text.

Below is the code:

```
urls = {}
s = requests.session()

for a,b in all_sitemaps.items():
    for urls in b:
        one_sitemap = urls
        pip_sitemap = s.get(one_sitemap)
        soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(pip_sitemap.text,'html.parser')
        s = soup.find_all("loc")
        
        for url in s:
            loc = url.getText()

            if loc not in urls:
                urls[loc] = []
            for b in a.findNextSiblings():
                if b.get("href") != None:
                    urls[loc].append(b.get("href"))
```

I wish to scrap all `<loc>urls</loc>` from all the sitemap files stored as sublists in `all_sitemaps` dict but the program runs only one iteration over first list element `https://www.example.com/file-1.xml` and starts throwing an error as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [231], line 7
      5 for urls in b:
      6     one_sitemap = urls
----> 7     pip_sitemap = s.get(one_sitemap)
      8     soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(pip_sitemap.text,'html.parser')
      9     s = soup.find_all("loc")

File c:\Users\natan12\Documents\My-Work-Files\python\udemy\vs_code\ARTOO\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py:2289, in ResultSet.__getattr__(self, key)
   2287 def __getattr__(self, key):
   2288     """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
-> 2289     raise AttributeError(
   2290         "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2291     )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

When I try to run in small iterations to print all sitemaps as strings it works fine so can someone please suggest how to overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: I have added the full stack error in my question. Thanks!

Comment: The code snippet doesn't match the code shown in the traceback.

Comment: my apologies Michael. I was trying to be precise but now I have pasted full code.

Comment: You are using variable "s" first for the requests session but overwrite it then with a Beautifulsoup ResultSet so that in the second iteration of the `for urls in b` loop the code tries to access a "get" attribute of the ResultSet.

Comment: Please see what a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is. Either confirm the url of the page you're trying to scrape (if publicly accessible), or alternatively post the page html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two different variables, both named `s`

> ```py
> s = requests.session()
> ```

and

> ```py
>         s = soup.find_all("loc") ## the ResultSet
> ```

that is why, in the a lofter the first iteration or the *`for urls in b:...`* loop,
`s.get(one_sitemap)` will raise error, because it is no longer a `requests.sessions.Session` object but is now a `bs4.element.ResultSet` object.

---

**You should rename one of them**, like

```py
        loc_rs = soup.find_all("loc") ## renamed var
        
        for url in loc_rs: ## use renamed var
            loc = url.getText()
```

or

```py
sess = requests.session() ## renamed var

for a,b in all_sitemaps.items():
    for urls in b:
        one_sitemap = urls
        pip_sitemap = sess.get(one_sitemap) ## use renamed var
        soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(pip_sitemap.text,'html.parser')
```

---

You can also just directly loop through `.find_all` - no need for saving the second `s` variable.

```py
        for url in soup.find_all("loc"):
            loc = url.getText()
```